# how to speed up mysql query execution?

Tags: mysql, sql

[output of this query](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FlxDf.png) i have a little bit complex query, it takes about 3 minutes to fetch 100 records. how do i tweak the query to speed up its execution? i am using mysql.

i have already added indexes on possible fields.

```
EXPLAIN SELECT RESULT.*,IFNULL(RESULT1.AVG_WEEK_TIME_SPENT,0) AVG_WEEK_TIME_SPENT FROM (
    SELECT I.ID,I.CLIENT_INST_ID,I.NAME,U2.USERNAME INSTITUTE_EMAIL,
    IFNULL(SUM(TD.TIME_SPENT),0) TOTAL_TIME_SPENT,COUNT(DISTINCT U.ID) REGISTERED_USER,
    COUNT(DISTINCT TD.user_id) ACTIVE_USER,
    IFNULL(IFNULL(SUM(TD.TIME_SPENT),0)/COUNT(DISTINCT TD.user_id),0) AVG_TIME_SPENT
    FROM cloudCore.USER U,cloudCore.USER U2,client219.INSTITUTE I,client219.INSTITUTE_USER_MAP IUM
    LEFT OUTER JOIN client219.LICENSE_CONSUMPTION LC ON LC.user_id = IUM.ID AND LC.CONSUMPTION <='2019-02-28 23:59:59'
    LEFT OUTER JOIN client219.USER_BOOK UB ON UB.institute_user_id =LC.user_id AND (UB.EXPIRY_DATE >='2018-02-01 00:00:00' OR UB.EXPIRY_DATE IS NULL)
    LEFT OUTER JOIN analytics.TRACKING_DATA TD ON UB.institute_user_id=TD.user_id AND TD.INSTITUTE_ID=IUM.institute_id AND  TD.client_id=219
    AND TD.LAST_ACCESSED >='2018-02-01 00:00:00' AND TD.LAST_ACCESSED <='2019-02-28 23:59:59'
    WHERE U.client_id=219 AND U.LEVEL=2 AND IUM.user_id=U.ID AND U.DELETED = 0
    AND IUM.institute_id = I.ID AND U2.id=I.ADMIN_ID AND U2.client_id=U.client_id
    GROUP BY I.ID ) RESULT
    LEFT OUTER JOIN
 (SELECT I.ID,IFNULL(IFNULL(SUM(TD.TIME_SPENT),0)/COUNT(DISTINCT TD.user_id),0) AVG_WEEK_TIME_SPENT
FROM cloudCore.USER U,client219.INSTITUTE I,client219.INSTITUTE_USER_MAP IUM
LEFT OUTER JOIN client219.LICENSE_CONSUMPTION LC ON LC.user_id = IUM.ID AND LC.CONSUMPTION <='2019-02-28 23:59:59'
LEFT OUTER JOIN client219.USER_BOOK UB ON UB.institute_user_id =LC.user_id AND (UB.EXPIRY_DATE >='2018-02-01 00:00:00' OR UB.EXPIRY_DATE IS NULL)
LEFT OUTER JOIN analytics.TRACKING_DATA TD ON UB.institute_user_id=TD.user_id AND TD.INSTITUTE_ID=IUM.institute_id AND  TD.client_id=219
AND TD.LAST_ACCESSED>=DATE_ADD('2019-02-28 23:59:59',INTERVAL -7 DAY)  AND TD.LAST_ACCESSED <='2019-02-28 23:59:59'  
WHERE U.client_id=219 AND U.LEVEL=2 AND IUM.user_id=U.ID AND U.DELETED = 0
AND IUM.institute_id = I.ID AND U.CREATED_BY>=DATE_ADD('2019-02-28 23:59:59',INTERVAL -7 DAY)
GROUP BY I.ID) RESULT1 ON RESULT.ID=RESULT1.ID;
```

Comment: can you add the output of the EXPLAIN statement to your question? Also without the table schemata and the indices, how do you expect to get help?

Comment: `FROM cloudCore.USER U,client219.INSTITUTE I,client219.INSTITUTE_USER_MAP IUM
LEFT OUTER JOIN`  ... Mixing comma join syntax and explicit JOIN syntax can be asking for trouble as it seams you never filter that resultset to a INNER JOIN the `FROM cloudCore.USER U,client219.INSTITUTE I,client219.INSTITUTE_USER_MAP IUM` parts seams to be running as a CROSS JOIN

Comment: hello @neuhaus i have edited post to add output of this query.

Comment: @RaymondNijland  i believe i am not doing here cross join.? and if it does,  does it affect the query execution time?

Comment: Well i just noticed there are limitting factors.. `IUM.user_id=U.ID` but using comma join and explicit JOIN syntax are hard to read and understand what is going to happen.. Still it can be asking for trouble..

Comment: But the question as it is now it is very unclear.. As we need to know the indexes/datatypes of the tables... Ideally we need to have the `CREATE TABLE` statements (`SHOW CREATE TABLE table`) for every table involved in the query... Also ideally you could also consider giving example data and expected results based on that example data..

Comment: ...  as rewitting the SQL might be needed to gain performance that way we can also verify our query.  See [Why should I provide a Minimal Reproducible Example for a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: This query is too long/complex for SO. A general approach: Build the query from scratch - step by step, until it becames to be slow. Then fix that step.